# Fragment which is not top most in backstack is resumed

Tags: android, android-fragments, onresume, back-stack

Given the application flow show in the graphic and textually described in the following.

[image: Application flow]

1. Fragment 1 is the lowest fragment but not in the backstack by setting `disallowAddToBackStack`.
2. Fragment 2 is pushed onto the stack, using `fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack()`.
3. A new instance of fragment 1 is pushed onto the stack.
4. The top most fragment (fragment 1) is popped from the stack.
5. Activity 2 becomes foreground.
6. Activity 1 becomes foreground.

Here is the generalized method I use to handle fragments:

```
private void changeContainerViewTo(int containerViewId,  Fragment fragment, 
                                   Activity activity, String backStackTag) {

    if (fragmentIsAlreadyPresent(containerViewId, fragment, activity)) { return; }
    final FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = 
                 activity.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(containerViewId, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
    if (backStackTag == null) {
        fragmentTransaction.disallowAddToBackStack();
    } else {
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(backStackTag);
    }
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

## Problem

When activity 1 resumes in the last step the lowest instance of fragment 1 also resumes. At this point in time fragment 1 returns `null` on `getActivity()`.

## Question

- Why is a fragment which is not the top most on the stack resumed?
- If resuming the fragment is correct - how should I handle a detached fragment?

Comment: Is First Fragment1 and Fragment2 are use same container view and what transaction you use on second step?

Comment: Yes, Fragment1 and Fragment2 use the same container view.

Comment: And what about about transaction type: "replace", "add"?

Comment: @Evos All transactions are done via `fragmentTransaction.replace(containerViewId, fragment)`.

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me. It should either show F1 if A1 has been destroyed (in that cause you won't be getting a null on getActivity) or F2 if A1 has not been destroyed. You are using the latest support library right?

Comment: I have similar problem that best of all described by the title of your post. Did you manage to resolve yours?

Comment: @NeviQ-OR Somewhat. It is too long ago that I could explain it in detail though. Please feel free to **create a new question** and link it in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

When an `Activity` is not showing UI and then come to show UI, the `FragmentManager` associated is dying with all of your fragments and you need to restore its state.

As the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) says:

> There are many situations where a fragment may be mostly torn down (such as when placed on the back stack with no UI showing), but its state will not be saved until its owning activity actually needs to save its state.

In your `Activity` `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState`, try saving you `Fragment` references and then restore them with something like this:

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
    getFragmentManager().putFragment(outState,"myfragment", myfragment);
}
public void onRetoreInstanceState(Bundle inState){
    myFragment = getFragmentManager().getFragment(inState, "myfragment");
}
```

Try this out and have luck! :-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how this would happen, unless (based on how you described the steps) you've misunderstood how fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack() works: it manages which transactions are placed in backstack, not fragments.

From the android docs:

> By calling addToBackStack(), the replace transaction is saved to the
>   back stack so the user can reverse the transaction and bring back the
>   previous fragment by pressing the Back button.

So if your step 2 looked something like this in code:

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(containerViewId, fragment2);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack();
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

and your step 3:

```
fragmentTransaction.disallowAddToBackStack()//or just no call to addToBackStack - you do not say
fragmentTransaction.replace(containerViewId, newfragment1);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

At this point, Fragment2 will be removed from the backstack, and your backstack consists of the two Fragment1 instances. in Step 4 you pop the top one, which means you should have the bottommost Fragment1 now at the top.

This explains why it is the resumed fragment if you return to the activity. But not, i'm afraid, why it is apparently detached from its activity.

Comment: I noticed that you call `.disallowAddToBackStack()` before `.replace()`. See my updated question. Could that be a problem?

Comment: no, the order doesn't matter. it's just attributes you set as you build you transaction, not used until you finally call commit.

Comment: if you're currently doing something like 
step1)`changeContainerViewTo(containerId,afragment1,activity,null)`
step2)`changeContainerViewTo(containerId,afragment2,activity,tag)`
step3)`changeContainerViewTo(containerId,afragment1,activity,null)`

that's probably not doing what you want - try passing null for step2's tag param, and a non-null value for step3's tag param. in short, you only want to call addToBackStack when the fragment BEING replaced in a transaction is what you want to save in back history.

Answer (score 1):

Android OS can and will create and destroy fragments when it sees fit.  This is likely happening when you launch Activity 2 and return to Activity 1.  I'd verify for sure that it isn't the actively displayed fragment.  What is probably happening is that you are seeing it do some of the creation steps for fragment 1 before it does the creation steps for fragment 2.

As for handling the detached fragments you should take a look at this [page](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html).  The gist of it is that you should only be using the getActivity in certain fragment functions(Based on the [fragment life cycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating)).  This might mean that you have to move some of your logic to other functions.